# Error after switching from Webpack Encore to AssetMapper: "Asset manifest file does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-assetmapper

After installing AssetMapper and removing Webpack Encore in Symfony 7.0, I'm now getting this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "/.../public/build/manifest.json" does not exist. Did you forget to build the assets with npm or yarn?").

It's reported at this line in my `base.html.twig`:

```
{% block importmap %}{{ importmap('app') }}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from the [`json_manifest_path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#json-manifest-path) setting somewhere in your `config/` folder (probably `config/packages/assets.yaml` or `config/packages/framework.yaml`).

Solution: Just delete that setting :-)